# Sample program using Function Pointer and structures.

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I created a structure and wanted to assign the values to a Function Pointer of another structure. The sample code I wrote is like below. Please see what else I've missed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct PClass{

void *Funt;    

}gpclass;

struct StrFu stringfunc;

struct  StrFu{
    int a ;
    char c;

};

Initialise(){



}

main()
{
    stringfunc.a = 5;
    stringfunc.c = 'd';

    gpclass.Funt = malloc(sizeof(struct StrFu));

    gpclass.Funt = &stringfunc;
    memcpy(gpclass.Funt,&stringfunc,sizeof(struct StrFu));

printf("%u %u",gpclass.Funt->a,gpclass.Funt->c);

}
```

Comment: What's your problem here?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Where is the function you want to point, and where is the pointer to function ?

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems:

1. A function pointer is not the same as `void *`, in fact you cannot rely on being able to convert between them.
2. [You shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).
3. You shouldn't call `malloc()`, then overwrite the returned pointer.
4. You don't need to use `malloc()` to store a single pointer, just use a pointer.
5. You shouldn't use `memcpy()` to copy structures, just use assignment.
6. There are two valid `main()` prototypes: `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, and you're not using either.

Comment: regarding 1. it does not look like he wants to use pointer to function, it is just the name of pointer misleading. anyway +1

Comment: Note of course that while the C standard does not require function pointers to be compatible with `void *`, there is a requirement in POSIX for this to be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

there is lots of problem in your code , I try to correct it ,hope it will help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct PClass{

void *Funt;

}gpclass;



struct  StrFu{
    int a ;
    char c;

};

struct StrFu stringfunc;

int main()
{
    stringfunc.a = 5;
    stringfunc.c = 'd';

    gpclass.Funt = malloc(sizeof(struct StrFu));

    gpclass.Funt = &stringfunc;
    memcpy(gpclass.Funt,&stringfunc,sizeof(struct StrFu));

    printf("%d %c",((struct StrFu*)gpclass.Funt)->a,((struct  StrFu*)gpclass.Funt)->c);
    return 0;
}
```

it outputs

5  d

Comment: -1, keeps the broken `main()`, the pointless `malloc()`, the the super-pointless `memcpy()`. Very bad answer, imo.

Comment: @Micheal: If I need to copy the information of  this generic pointer into a buffer ,(char *buffer). How to achieve ?

Comment: memcpy(buffer, (struct StrFu*)gpclass.Funt, sizeof(gpclass.Funt)) will copy only the pointer instead of data, right?